# Managed Stacks in Process Monitor

Tags: .net, debugging, sysinternals

Is it possible to see managed stack traces in Process Monitor for file access events of a given process? If not, is there the other way to accomplish such task?

Comment: Process Monitor is an unmanaged tool and records the native stack trace.  You need a managed debugger to see the stack frames generated by the jitted code.  Preventing the jitter from generating code is possible, use ngen.exe /debug on the program.  No idea if that makes ProcMon smarter, possibly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately Process Monitor does not yet support managed call stacks. But [perfview](https://github.com/Microsoft/perfview/blob/master/documentation/Downloading.md) is pretty good at decomposing managed stacks and it also provides a way to collect File I/O events:

#### Select File I/O events in Run/Collect dialog:

[image]

#### After tracing is finished you should have File I/O events available in the directory tree:

[image]

#### Double clicking it should present you a window with all collected File I/O operations

[image]

Each operation has a call stack registered and you may browse it on other tabs available in the events window.